# How do I store drop down values into my table so it displays the value chosen?

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 values in my `dropdown` i.e : male or female. I want to display the `selected option` into my table.

```
 Gender: <select name="dropdownvalues" >  
     <option value="Male">Male</option>  
     <option value="Female">Female</option>
```

I am fairly new to JSP. This is what I have in my table.

```
<table border="1" style="width: 800px;">
<tr style="background-color: yellow;">
<td>Number</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Male or Female</td>
</tr>

<%
Map<String, String> mapData=(Map<String,String>)session.getAttribute
("mapData");
if(mapData!=null) {
Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> rows = mapData.entrySet();
int count = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String,String> row : rows){
%>

<tr>
<td><%= ++count %></td>
<td><%= row.getKey() %></td>
<td><%= row.getValue() %></td>
<td></td><!-- how to get male or female? -->

</tr>
<%      
}
}
%>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry wasn't sure why my code didn't come up. Redited

Comment: show your `session.setAttribute` code,where you are setting values for other fields.

Comment: Sorry learning JSP, I don't know any JS. The table is separate from my drop down page. This table is a separate page to display my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP could retrieve server-state objects (send with request, session, etc.). You need to declare some class i.e:

```
public class MyData {

private int count;
private String name;
private String email;
private boolean gender; //also you can use enum here to support another genders :)

//Getters, constructors here
}
```

And instead of having in your jsp

```
Map<String, String> mapData=(Map<String,String>)session.getAttribute
("mapData");
```

you may have `List<MyData>` and get all data you need from it.

Comment: Hmm so I would declare this in my servlet? And retrieve it from my jsp page? For example if I did String gender = request.getParameter("dropdownvalues"); in my servlet. What would be the correct way to call it on my jsp page? Sorry if it doesn't make sense. Still learning

Comment: Declare this class in (i.e.)`src/main/java/yourpackage/model`, create instances in servlet which handles saving operation